# Rule of thumb for the number of unique values from a distribution drawing

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

My main problem is to count the number of unique values (number of symbols) drawn from a specific finite distribution $(p_i)$ of $m$ symbols, after $n$ drawings. The difficulty is to estimate it without access to the distribution: by knowing only a few parameters.

Following [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/444547/89999), we define: $$X_i =
\begin{cases}
1,    &\text{if at least one i is drawn, for i = 1, 2, ..., m}\\
0,    &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

so that the number of unique symbols is
$$U = \sum_{i=1}^m E(X_i) = m - \sum_{i=1}^m (1-p_i)^n$$

I would like to approximate $U$ only using $n$ and some parameters from $(p_i)$: mean, variance, or entropy for instance. The goal is not to have a very precise result but more a rule of thumb. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: At your definition of $X_i$ you let $i$ start at $0$.

Comment: @drhab Fixed, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one, admittedly rough, bound:

We can define $q_i=1-p_i$ then $U=m - \sum_{i=1}^m q_i^n$. This imposes the constraints $ 0\leq q_i\leq 1, \text{ and }\sum_{i=1}^m q_i=m-1$.

We can minimize $g(\mathbf{q}):=\sum_{i=1}^m q_i^n$ by setting $q_i=\frac{m-1}{m}$ (from symmetry and the special case where $m=2$), which represents the case when every object has an equal chance of being chosen. $g$ is maximized by setting $q_i=1,\; i<m,\; \text{ and } q_m=0$) Which implies that only 1 object really has a chance of being chosen.

This gives bounds for $U$:

$$ 1\leq U \leq m-\frac{(m-1)^n}{m^{n-1}} $$

Note that $\lim_{n\to \infty} m-\frac{(m-1)^n}{m^{n-1}} = m,
\; m>0$